# Does complementary relation($\overline R$) is transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, relations

Let $R$ be a relation that is transitive. Does complementary of $R$ ($\overline R$) is  transitive?($\overline R$is  hold transitive)

Comment: You need more hypotheses, because as it stands, the statement is false: $\varnothing$ and $A\times A$ are complementary, transitive relations on $A$.

Comment: Sorry.I think new question is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true, even for nontrivial relations.

For instance, consider $R \subseteq \{ 1,2,3 \}^2$ given by
$$R = \{ (1,2),(1,3),(2,3) \}$$
Then $R$ is transitive, and
$$\bar R = \{(1,1), (2,1), (2,2), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3) \}$$
which is also transitive.

---

**Edit:** Even with the question edit, the result still doesn't hold. For instance, let $R = \{ (1,3) \}$ on the set $\{1,2,3\}$. Then $(1,2) \in \bar R$ and $(2,3) \in \bar R$ but $(1,3) \not \in \bar R$, so $\bar R$ is not transitive, even though $R$ is transitive.

Comment: Or more generally $<$ and $\ge$, where $<$ is any linear order on the underlying set.

Comment: Sorry,I edited body of question.

Comment: @geni: It still doesn't hold; see my edit.

Comment: (I may have missed something though; I don't know what 'hold transitive' means.)

Answer (score 2):

Knowing only that a relation is transitive doesn't allow you to conclude anything about the transitivity of its complement.

For example the standard order relation $<$ on the integers is transitive, but its complement $\geq$ is also transitive.

On the other hand, the equality relation $=$ on the integers is transitive, but its complement $\neq$ is not.